# unreachable statement

Tags: java, loops

I have loop designed to validate the user input on a question, it was working fine until I added this;

```
        if (userInput.charAt(0) > NUMCOLS && userInput.charAt(0) < 0);
        {
            System.out.println("Error, " + userInput + " is an invalid move.");
            continue;
        }
```

before this

```
        if (userInput.charAt(2) !='-')
        {
            System.out.println("Error, " + userInput + " is an invalid move.");
            continue;
        }
```

Now whenever I try to compile I get an error stating that this is an **unreachable statement**, what is causing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a spurious ';' in the first line of your added code that makes the first `continue;` always execute!

Answer (score 3):

Both of those conditions cannot be true at the same time, and the compiler is aware of this.

Read it out loud :

If the user inputs first character is greater than NUMCOLS *and* its less than 0!  If NUMCOLS is 0 or greater, the second condition cannot be true at the same time, and vice versa.

Comment: OK - I'm wrong about this being the cause of your compilation error, but your logic does seem wrong.  How can both of those conditions be true at the same time?

Comment: Actually this is the next problem I've run into, here's what I'm testing;

if (userInput.charAt(0) < 0 && userInput.charAt(0) > (NUMCOLS+1))

what I'm trying to do is create a game of checkers, I'm checking to make sure the number entered by the player is between the range of 1 and 8, NUMCOLS is a variable being used to determine the size of the  checkerboard (in this case 7, but the board is being drawn 1-8 instead of 0-7, hence adding 1 to NUMCOLS)

No matter what I enter it always returns false to the condition and skips the error...

Comment: So what you want is userInput.charAt(0) >= 1 && userInput.charAt(0) < 9)

Comment: That still doesn't work, I only want it to be true if the value entered is outside the range, hence returning the error.

No matter what I enter at the moment I receive a false...

Comment: Ah, so what you want is: userInput.charAt(0) < 0 || userInput.charAt(0) > 8

Comment: You understand why, right?  It's important to think this through.

Answer (score 3):

your `if` test has an empty body!

so the code below is always executed and since there's a `continue` code the following instructions are never executed..